# Using GraphQL Plugin with Pods Framework

Tags: custom-post-types, open-graph, pods-framework

So, I started to experiment with a [GraphQL plugin for WP](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql), and was wondering how it'd work with Pods.

I came across [a question](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/322#issuecomment-347283917) on that plugin's GitHub that's pretty much the same thought I had. The maintainers supplied an answer:

> Each Custom Post Type and Custom Taxonomy you want to add to the Schema should have the following fields set:
>
> - show_in_graphql (bool)
> - graphql_single_name (string)
> - graphql_plural_name (string)

I think I know how to do it with directly creating a custom post type [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) in PHP, but not sure how I'd do it in Pods.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely add filters for `pods_register_post_type_{your_pod}` and `pods_register_taxonomy_{your_pod}`. I'd love to build in support for GraphQL into Pods itself at some point. Just a matter of adding the checks if GraphQL is available and showing the options in the UI, similar to how we do our REST API options in the UI.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'pods_register_post_type_mycpt', 'add_pods_graphql_support' );
add_filter( 'pods_register_taxonomy_mytax', 'add_pods_graphql_support' );

function add_pods_graphql_support( $options ) {

    $options['show_in_graphql'] = true;
    $options['graphql_single_name'] = $options['labels']['name'];
    $options['graphql_plural_name'] = $options['labels']['singular_name'];

    return $options;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Was not expecting an answer from the maintainer :) 

I tried it out, and it seems adding the support (via `$options['show_in_graphql'] = true;`) does something, but breaks something on the GraphQL plugin side. I'll have to look into it!

Comment: is it possible to query fields too? We have a custom taxonomy which we have registered for graph like so ```add_filter( 'pods_register_taxonomy_pa_0500_provider', 'add_pods_graphql_support' );```

The the provider also has a pods field attached to it , "logo" But we cant see that in the graphql query response.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me, but I also need to add to the graphql schema all the custom fields I assigned to the pods custom type.. is there a way to do that?